# I am attempting to print an each array values in table format.But i having a trouble in this code

Tags: php, arrays, linkedin-api, stdclass

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [_total] => 2 
    [values] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [degree] => BCA 
            [endDate] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2012 )
            [fieldOfStudy] => Computer Application 
            [id] => 170345308 [schoolName] => Tagore College of Arts and science 
            [startDate] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2009 ) 
        ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( 
            [degree] => BCA 
            [endDate] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2012 ) 
            [fieldOfStudy] => Computer Application 
            [id] => 170345431 
            [schoolName] => Tagore College of Arts and science 
            [startDate] => stdClass Object ( [year] => 2009 ) 
        ) 
     ) 
)
```

I would like to print the array values of this above code. I use print_r function it will print all values.
but I need individual values in table format like schoolname and their corresponding value and so on.

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <th>schoolname</th>
        <th>field of study</th>
        <th>start date</th>
        <th>end date</th>
        <th>degree</th>
        <th>activites</th>
        </tr>
            <?php
            for($i=0;$i<$user->educations['total'];$i++)
            {   ?>
                <tr>
            <td><?php echo $user->educations['values'][$i]['schoolName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->educations['values'][$i]['degree'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->educations['values'][$i]['fieldOfStudy'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->educations['values'][$i]['startDate']['year'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->educations['values'][$i]['endDate']['year'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: echo $your_object_var->FlightInfoResult->flights->originCity;

Comment: Could you please share with us your attempts thus far?

Answer (score 1):

Your object var_dump is contains an array of objects but in your code you are just using array syntax which is where your problems are probably coming from. Below is an example of how you could approach this.

Firstly notice the change from using a for to a foreach. It is good practice to use a foreach when iterating over every element in an array. It makes code easier to understand as well as removing the iterator variable
    $i.

Secondly notice how

Finally notice the change from using the array syntax $education['value'] to $education->value.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>schoolname</th>
        <th>field of study</th>
        <th>start date</th>
        <th>end date</th>
        <th>degree</th>
        <th>activites</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($educations->values as $education) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $education->schoolName ?></td>
        <td><?= $education->degree ?></td>
        <td><?= $education->fieldOfStudy ?></td>
        <td><?= $education->startDate->year ?></td>
        <td><?= $education->endDate->year ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be;

```
$variable->FlightInfoResult->flights->originCity
```